# I upgraded Flutter (and Dart), now I can't get WebApps to work

Tags: flutter, dart

2 days ago, I upgraded Flutter to 1.9,  and Web Apps worked like a charm.  Today I did another upgrade to 1.10 and now I can't get Web Aps to work.  I'm running Windows 10.  Below is some console output.  Commands are in **BOLD**  thanks.

I don't get any error messages. A new Chrome browser opens with "localhost:51538" - but it's just a blank page.  The app runs fine in an emulator.

**N:\dev\test_web>flutter  --version**

Flutter 1.10.6-pre.29 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 919cc97f6a (19 hours ago) • 2019-09-20 14:57:05 -0700
Engine • revision 99092a0436
Tools • Dart 2.6.0 (build 2.6.0-dev.1.0 7c1821c4aa)

**flutter devices**
2 connected devices:

Chrome • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 76.0.3809.132
Server • web    • web-javascript • Flutter Tools

**flutter create test_web**
**cd test_web**
**flutter run -d chrome**

Launching lib\main.dart on Chrome in debug mode...
Building application for the web...                                17.8s

Warning: Flutter's support for building web applications is highly experimental.
For more information see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34082.

To hot restart (and rebuild state), press "R".
For a more detailed help message, press "h". To quit, press "q"
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51693/YeZi5VuCO6U=

Comment: Flutter has merged its web branch with the main branch. So now you don't need to import web components explicitly. This may be the cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

flutter run --release -d chrome -v

it'll run with this command ,
it's not the best solution but works, it creates a release version always, development is very slow with this,
let me know if you find any better solution than this

Comment: the debug versions are crashing as if now, that's why you can't see the log and it shows only a white screen, it'll be fixed soon i think

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I can just do my development using the emulator, and occasionally check the web app.  Not perfect, but they warned me this was not-ready-for-prime-time.

Comment: Have you got a better solution?